# Submit Contact Form without using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, forms, feedback, contact-form

I'm still a student and today our lecturer told us that the only way in order to submit a contact us form without having to use the mailto: function is to use PHP.

I swear that last year another lecturer showed us a way using only javascript.

Is it possible to submit a feedback/contact form using a basic form and javascript ? If so, do you mind sharing a sample example ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Can JavaScript email a form?](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-email-form.phtml)

Comment: This answer to this other SO question suggests to use http://formspree.io :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28536121/311288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to redirect to `mailto:` with some parameters, but that isn't ideal.  Also keep in mind that anything beyond an e-mail address in a `mailto:` URL is non-standard.  While it will work for many browsers, it won't work for everything.

The best way to send e-mail is to do it server-side, using PHP or something else.

Comment: so there is no way that the email can be sent without opening the client's default mail viewer and having them click send ?

Answer (score 2):

A form is created/submitted by the browser based on HTML. JavaScript is commonly used to enhance forms (in many different ways). Basic forms send their data as a POST request. To do anything useful with the data you need server-side code to handle the POST request (such as PHP).

Answer (score 1):

You can't submit a form to javascript and expect it to do anything. You need a server side script in order to receive a form for processing. Mailto is a browser/os specific method and is not necessarily going to invoke anything. Javscript can process your form before going to the server for further processing, but like I said you need to submit to a server.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript cant capture anything without PHP or browser support. You need a server side script to receive a form and process it. Javascript without PHP or another server side script can't capture form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service like [emailjs.com](https://www.emailjs.com/):

1) Configure EmailJS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.emailjs.com/sdk/2.2.4/email.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function(){
      emailjs.init("user_USERID");
   })();
</script>
```

2) Send the Email:

```
var service_id = 'my_mandrill';
var template_id = 'feedback';
var template_params = {
    name: 'John',
    reply_email: 'john@doe.com',
    message: 'This is awesome!'
};

emailjs.send(service_id,template_id,template_params);
```

It has a limit of 200 free emails per month, which will suite a resume/portfolio website. reCaptcha is supported.

EmailJS supports different Email providers (including a custom SMTP server), and provides you with logs and statistics.