# Send email from html form without php

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Is there a service that allows you to post a form to it from an html page (my php mail isn't working temporarily and I need a quick solution) and it will automatically send an email with specified content to a specified address?

The address it comes from is insignificant.

Comment: Put `mailto:address` in the `action` of the form, and it will start up the user's mail client to send the form as email.

Comment: It has to be automated. The user shouldnt have to send the email themself. I just need a php script on an external website that sends mail to a specified address that I can post my form to and then have it redirect to a thank you page

Comment: How come this is off-topic and this isn't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419118/email-contact-form-without-php

Comment: @steffen Good question -- and the fact that this post continues to receive upvotes means it's valuable to alot of people who care less about following SO guidelines than they do about finding actual solutions to coding challenges many people have.

Comment: Checkout https://web3forms.com/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no perfect solution because they are still encoded as url variables.  Setting the enctype to plaintext makes it somewhat more acceptable.

```
<form action="mailto:email@example.com" enctype="text/plain">
<textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 31):

Check out formspree.

https://github.com/asm-products/formspree

For action you simply put:

```
<form action="http://formspree.io/you@email.com" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="email" name="_replyto">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
```

After verifying your email after the first send this will email you the contents of the form. One thing to keep in mind is that this will take the input names. If you do not include input names it won't send you that form field.

Comment: Yeah.. formspree is really good. Also check www.enformed.io Works great too..

Comment: Thanks for that.  Enformed.io is better for me as they support AJAX posts (without charging more like formspree).

Comment: Not a good Idea, it's paid.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you can within the website. As the others stated, you can use mailto:someone@blahblah.com, but that is not automatic and it opens the user's default email editor. You could use http://www.emailmeform.com/ though. It lets you make a form and it will send an email to you.

Answer (score 3):

in your html form provide a `mailto` action.

for example

```
<form action="mailto:yourdest@email.com">
.....
</form>
```