# Sending HTML Bootstrap form to email

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web, modal-dialog

How would I go about sending information from my bootstrap modal form to an email account? I have been looking around and seeing people using php. Is there no way to do this without php? And if so how would I go about starting this since I have no clue how to use php? I am trying to build my own website and would like to add this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this without server-side code (PHP for example).

Here's another post with a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11419187/881011

Answer (score 0):

Im almost confident php is required.  And im pretty sure it would go through you hosting plan (godaddy, host gator, etc) you will have to check out you hosting plan.  I've never done it my self but from my understanding there is a way and php is required. 
    :) host hope this helps.